# how to deliver parameters in a anchor url in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to deliver an id in anchor url, but when i do like this

```
 $<a href="#editEmployeeModal?id=<?php $valeur['idu']"  </a>
```

the anchor stoped working .

all the other information that I found are about a url for another php page.

thanks.

Comment: Hi, can you provide us with some code to see what you have and is not working?

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to close the tag. Try `<a href="#editEmployeeModal?id=<?php $valeur['idu']">Click here</a>`

Comment: But you know, if you click on an anchor with a #, it just jumps to another place in the page. What do you expect to happen when you add the id to the querystring, exactly?

Comment: The query string goes **before** the fragment identifier, not after it.

Comment: < a href="#editEmployeeModal?id= < ? php echo valeur['id'] >"  class="edit" data-toggle="modal" > < /a >    this 's the code

Comment: @ADyson i want to use this id in another part of  the page to modify my data base

Comment: @Quentin can you give me an example

Comment: "i want to use this id in another part of the page to modify my data base"...but you know that clicking this anchor link doesn't post back to the server, right? So you'll have to handle the click event on the anchor using JavaScript and run some code to read the ID from the querystring and do something e.g. run an AJAX request. maybe you already thought of this, I don't know, but just pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Add `echo` to output the variable, and close php tag.

```
<a href="#editEmployeeModal?id=<?php echo valeur['id']; >" class="edit" data-toggle="modal"> </a>
```